# why is my generator running but you cant plug in anything

Tags: generator

we have a new smart tool 4750 gas generator and it was working fine when we plugged it into our rv then all of sudden it stopped putting out charge but it still turns over and sounds like its working but if you plug in anything it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Did you check to verify the circuit breakers haven't tripped. I attempted to find a manual on line and was unable to download the file from the SmartTool web site. I was checking to see if the unit came with replaceable brushes in the generator. Brush failure is pretty common issue with discount generators. If you can get replacement parts they are usually easy to replace. It can be as simple as unscrewing the cap, pull out the spring and carbon brush and install the new one. If you remove the old ones a local small engine shop may be able to match them up with a generic part.

Comment: Mikes and OP here is the link for the manual. Look at page 30 it is after 22. I know the numbers do not make sense but that is how the pages are in the download. http://www.usesmartertools.com/manuals/4750W%20Generator%20Manual12.pdf